# Problem sharing content from "private" site on facebook

Tags: facebook, private, sharing, addthis

I have a website that you can only access after login.

I want to be able to share some products on it, but when I click the share button, instead of sharing that particular item, it shares the the content for the main site.

It's like this, an example:

Main Site: www.xyz.com
Main site title: xyz.com
Main site description: site xyz

Product Site: www.xyz.com/product_b.php
Product page title: Product B
Product page description: check out this amazing product

When I click the share button on the product page, instead of sharing the product information, it shares the main site information... I guess it's related to being a private site...

I'm using addthis.com buttons to do it, but it's the same when I try to do it directly on facebook...

any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks,
Luis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a non-authorized user will be redirect to the "*main site*" then obviously Facebook (*when trying to get the details of the shared page*) will be redirected to the same page too!

From the documentation:

> The user agent of the scraper is:
>   "facebookexternalhit/1.1
>   (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

So you may capture this and allow access for Facebook scraper, but I really don't think you should do this (ethically). Instead, make a public page for each product were minimal data is shown and encourage users to register to view the full product page!

Just a side note (a reminder), always use the [Open Graph meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).