# Facebook like: pages that require a login

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a facebook like button on a page that requires that the user is logged in.  So when a user clicks the like button when they are logged in, it posts to their wall as "This user just liked Google Accounts www.mypage.com" I want people to be able to like the page but also want other users to see the proper page title and not Google Accounts.  I also only want the entire page visible to loggeed in users.

How do I let facebook see the page so it can scrape the proper title, but when users click on the link they are asked to login?

Comment: Regarding your "google-app-engine" tag... I'm not understanding the relevant connection here.

Comment: i guess google User service would be a better tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem sharing content from "private" site on facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371617/problem-sharing-content-from-private-site-on-facebook)

Comment: Again, you're very unclear in what you describe.  On my page's Like button, users ARE asked to login if they're not already... this is how Facebook works.

Comment: You don't even state [which method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you are using for putting the Like button on your page.

Comment: I think ifaour is pretty on track.  The problem is not with the like button, it's what is posted to the person's wall.  The scraper does not show the proper title because it is redirected to the Google Accounts sign-in page.  I was hoping there was a work around for this but if the other question is any indication there is not.